# A way to automatically cast string literals to `unsigned char*` in C?

Tags: c, casting, libxml2, string-literals

I'm using libxml2 for a project, and one of its quirks is that `xmlChar` is a typedef for `unsigned char` instead of just `char`. As far as I can tell, that doesn't have any effect on the actual execution, but it makes it really annoying to use string literals since I have to manually cast to `const xmlChar*`. All I really want is to be able to write `xmlGetProp(node, "some-property")` instead of `xmlGetProp(node, (const xmlChar*)"some-property")`. It may seem minor, but it makes the code significantly harder to read when every other statement has a `(const xmlChar*)` cast.

Is there a way to make `const char*` cast to `const xmlChar*` (`const unsigned char*`) without manual casts? Or alternately, is there a reason I shouldn't do this?

I assume this would be reasonably easy in C++, but I'm stuck with C.

Comment: Maybe you should submit a bug-fix to the project fixing their API... And no, it would not be any easier in C++.

Comment: `inline const unsigned char* ustring(const char* x) { return (const unsigned char*)x; }`? Use as `const xmlChar* x = ustring("foobar");`

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: That does not make the types identical, it only makes them have the same characteristics.

Comment: @pmr: Still a manual cast.

Comment: @Deduplicator My mistake. I misinterpreted the docs.

Comment: The `const` part of your manual cast is troublesome.  Won't  a `(xmlChar*)` work?

Comment: @Deduplicator making `xmlChar` be plain char is not quite that simple, as it may represent arrays of UTF8-encoded characters which would be more properly stored as unsigned chars to avoid the issues that come with negative characters.

Comment: Prior including xmlChar declaration do #define unsigned signed

Comment: You could make a macro to make it slightly more readable, e.g. `#define XSTR(str) (const xmlChar*)(str)`  , and use it as `xmlGetProp(node, XSTR("some-property"))`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: For that, you override the platform convention and just advice the compiler that plain `char` is `unsigned`, instead of mucking up your API.

Comment: please do not take Anonymous's suggestion!

Comment: #Deduplicator There may be other parts of the program which prefer plain char being signed, and the same setting has to be used for all TUs

Comment: @MattMcNabb I voted up the Anonymous suggestion because it's funny..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libxml2 defines a macro [`BAD_CAST`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html#BAD_CAST) in `xmlstring.h`:

```
#define BAD_CAST (xmlChar *)
```

It can be used like this:

```
xmlStrEqual(name, BAD_CAST "xml:lang")
```

Comment: I guess this is what the libxml2 people expect me to do :\

Comment: it's probably even worst than explicit C style cast or reinterpret_cast.
Every code analyser complains today about that. I still would like to understand the rationale for libxml2 api taking unsigned char *  as input.

Answer (score 1):

Issues with `char *` and `unsigned char *` are annoying , because (on 2's complement) they all point to the same thing. Even though aliasing via these types is permitted, the C standard requires a diagnostic. Some compilers have an option to suppress diagnostic for this case (when you omit the cast).

You could write some wrappers:

```
xmlChar *VxmlGetProp(const xmlNode *node, const char *name)
{
    return xmlGetProp(node, (const unsigned char *)name);
}
```

Note that I didn't write `const xmlChar` in the cast as this would silently cause broken behaviour if you later reconfigured libxml to use wide characters for `xmlChar`.

You could even use `const void *` as the argument type to allow your function to take both `const char *`, and `const unsigned char *`.

---

Another option (which also adds some typo-resistance) to your code would be to not use the string literals in place; instead have them in a table, e.g.

```
#define STRING_FOOBAR ((const unsigned char *)"foobar")
```

and then use `STRING_FOOBAR` in your code.